# Issue facing when automation scripts run in latest browser

Tags: java, windows, selenium, testng

Previously the scripts was running fine. But I am recently getting error when automation script is run in the below env.

> OS Version: Windows 7
>   
> Selenium Version: selenium-java-2.37.0
>   
> Driver Version: ChromeDriver 2.8

Getting error like:

```
Starting ChromeDriver (v2.8.241075) on port 22931
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
```

Now my chrome browser is updated to latest version. So I tried to download the latest selenium and chromedriver version. I tried to use below env.

> OS Version: Windows 7
>   
> Selenium version: selenium-java-3.7.1
>   
> Driver Version: ChromeDriver 2.33
>   
> Chrome Browser: Version 62.0.3202.94 (Official Build) (64-bit)

But I am still getting error like:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.<clinit>(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:146)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.HttpClientFactory.getClientConnectionManager(HttpClientFactory.java:71)
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved now. I updated my java version to 9 and used below env.

> Java version: 9.0.1
>   
> Selenium version: selenium-java-3.3.1
>   
> Driver Version: ChromeDriver 2.33 
>   
> Chrome Browser: Version 62.0.3202.94 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Answer (score 0):

Driver and browser compatibility issues are well known. The first one in most cases will have to catchup with the later. For example not all ChromeDriver versions are compatible with all versions of Chrome. One day you run test script, if it breaks, update the driver. Then it works. Or maybe one day Chrome has quietly updated itself without telling you. So it is a good practice to lock their versions explicitly (this includes disabling the browser updates).

One way to check those versions is to go through the current release notes of [ChromeDriver](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.33/notes.txt). In case this still doesn't help - downgrade either driver or browser pairs till it works. Couple of times I had to play the guessing game myself till make it work again.